# Intelli-J + Gradle + JRebel - Creating rebel.xml files that are of bogus path

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, jrebel

I've got my jrebel + intelliJ + gradle project all loaded.

I would like to be able to use jrebel to hot deploy any of the sub-modules of my gradle project. this project has many nested projects.

I use the Intelli-J jrebel plugin to create the rebel.xml files automatically by using the `View -> Tool Windows -> Jrebel` view and select the sub-modules that I want to hot deploy from.

The rebel.xml files it creates are set to listen to this directory: `/some/GradleProjectRoot/build/classes/production/submodule`

But intelliJ automatically compiles my source here: 
`/some/GradleProjectRoot/submodule/build/classes/main`

why did it choose this "production" directory and how can I get it to start using the right one?

NOTE: Editing the rebel.xml manually to the correct path works to get hot deploy running. but that's not ideal to edit 40 different rebel.xml files!

Comment: Are the rebel.xml-s still generated incorrectly in the latest versions?
Also make sure the uncheck `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> "Create separate module per source set"`. After this re-generate all rebel.xml-s. They should contain paths pointing to "build/classes/main" and "build/resources/main".

Comment: Yeah. I made sure I had the latest of absolutely everything. When I tried the "Create separate module per source set" it just made it worse. Then there was only 1 root project and it also had the `production/classes` folder which IntelliJ doesn't even build to. When I hit Build project in IntelliJ - it builds to the standard build/classes folder.